# Freehub has some play

Tags: wheels, freehub

I just got a new Zip 303s Wheelset and the freehub has some play that you can see on this [video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7gdc7seumfg3cz4/VIDEO-2020-11-04-11-13-23.mp4?dl=0). I am not sure whether this is normal or not.
Could you help me here?

Comment: A freehub on my DT Swiss hub can be easily lifted/detached by hand once the end cap is removed (also no tools, except some swearing is required). Can it be also the case for you? What about the whole real axle, is it also wobbly or just the freehub?

Comment: It is just the free hub. The axle is fix.

Comment: OK, have you tried installing the wheel and checking the play when it is tightened in the frame? Without a cassette, of course, just to feel how things work in the frame.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I installed it and everything is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got answer from the support:

> Due to the tool-free nature of endcap and freehub installation, there can be freehub play when the wheel is not installed in the frame. If you encounter the same movement when the wheel is in the bike, please contact your shop for service/warranty assistance.

Since the cassette is not wobbly when the wheel is installed everything is fine for me.